# How could this parsing code be made lazy depending on how much data is consumed on the output?

Tags: parsing, haskell

Do anyone have an idea how to make that code lazy and non-strict so it generates AST tree on parsing input data? Currently using lists input is read left to right, but constructed on reverse. Because of that I had to use "reverse" on two places.

```
type Program = [Instruction]
data Instruction = Next | Prev | Plus | Minus | Print | Loop [Instruction] deriving Show

parse :: String -> Program
parse ys = reverse exps where
        (exps, _) = parse' ys []
        parse' [] is     = (is, [])
        parse' (x:xs) is = case x of
                            '>' -> parse' xs (Next:is)
                            '<' -> parse' xs (Prev:is)
                            '+' -> parse' xs (Plus:is)
                            '-' -> parse' xs (Minus:is)
                            '.' -> parse' xs (Print:is)
                            '[' -> parse' after $ Loop (reverse inside):is where (inside, after) = parse' xs []
                            ']' -> (is, xs)
                            _   -> parse' xs is
```

Comment: A side note, you can un-indent those cases by quite a bit, and it'd be considered better style to put the `where` at the end of `parse'` instead of in the middle of the case.  If the values aren't used they won't be computed anyway, but it would keep that line from marching off the edge of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it lazy, then your function needs to return values that look like this:

```
instr1 : instr2 : ... : <thunk>
```

Where `<thunk>` is the rest of the computation. To me, this suggests your function should look like:

```
parse [] = []
parse (x:xs) = instr : parse xs
  where instr = ...
```

I don't know whether you did it deliberately or not, but that auxiliary `parse'` function with the extra argument in which you accumulate your results is exactly the pattern you'd use to get performance out of a *strict* language (if it supports tail call elimination). Tail recursion is actually the enemy here!

A tail recursive function with an accumulator is almost necessarily non-lazy, because it's not until you hit the base case and decide what to do with the final accumulator value that the first "piece" of the output can be known. So a consumer demanding your output must wait while you process the entire input, and your entire output must be buffered in memory.

The most obvious recipe for lazy recursive code is to for your function to return a data constructor (in this case `:`) applied to some fields, where your recursive call(s) are stored in one (or more) of the fields. This allows the consumer to inspect the constructor and any other fields you produced before demanding the output of your recursive call.

This also means that if you're writing a recursive function producing a recursive data type and you want it to be lazy, you often end up structuring your function after the structure of your return type - exactly the way recursive consumers usually mirror the structure of their *input* type. E.g. The prototypical list producer needs a case which returns `[]` and a case which returns `something : recursiveCall`.